# Unable to access variables when converting from application.cfm to application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

I am trying to convert an application I support from application.cfm to application.cfc.  I followed Ben Nadel's [ColdFusion Application.cfc Tutorial And Application.cfc Reference](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/726-ColdFusion-Application-cfc-Tutorial-And-Application-cfc-Reference.htm), but my pages cannot access any of the variables in the APPLICATION scope, without adding `APPLICATION.` to the variable.  As a side note, this application uses 0 cfc's currently.

here is my application.cfc.

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Application" hint="Handle the application" output="true">

    <cfset THIS.Name = "AAS" />
    <cfset THIS.ApplicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan( 0, 60, 0 , 0) />
    <cfset THIS.SessionManagement = true />
    <cfset THIS.setClientCookies = false />
    <cfset THIS.versionNum = '1'>
    <cfset THIS.genericUserID = 'o005265'>
    <cfset THIS.genericPassword = 'zo005265'>

    <cffunction 
        name="OnApplicationStart" 
        hint="Fires when the application is first created." 
        access="public" 
        output="false" 
        returntype="boolean">

       <cfset APPLICATION.aasURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8500/aaas'>
       <cfset APPLICATION.dsn = 've0_aaas'>
       <cfset APPLICATION.aas_system = 'development (studio)'>

    <cfreturn true />
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Basically I just copied what was in the application.cfm page, and figured it would work the same.  I am guessing that I have to invoke this somewhere?  That is the only thing that I can think of. Any help would be great.

--- EDIT ---

I have added the OnRequest and OnApplicationStart methods after @EvikJames answer

```
<cffunction name="OnApplicationStart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="false" hint="Fires when the application is first created.">
    <!--- Return out. --->
    <cfset APPLICATION.aasURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8500/aaas'>
    <cfset APPLICATION.datasource = 've0_aaas'>
    <cfset APPLICATION.aas_system = 'development (studio)'>
    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="OnRequest" access="public" returntype="void" output="true" hint="Fires after pre page processing is complete.">
    <!--- Define arguments. --->
    <cfargument name="TargetPage" type="string" required="true">
    <!--- Include the requested page. --->
    <cfinclude template="#ARGUMENTS.TargetPage#" />

    <cfset VARIABLES.dsn = APPLICATION.dsn>
    <cfset VARIABLES.aasURL = APPLICATION.aasURL>
    <cfset VARIABLES.aas_system = APPLICATION.aas_system>
    <!--- Return out. --->
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onApplication start method, do this:

```
<cfset APPLICATION.datasource = 'MyDSN'>
```

In your onRequest method, do this:

```
<cfset VARIABLES.DSN = APPLICATION.datasource>
```

Then, this query will work:

```
<cfquery datasource="#dsn#">
// sql
</cfquery>
```

I should add that when you are fully upgraded, you can remove all of the code above just set the default datasource:

```
<cfset THIS.datasource = 'MyDSN'>
```

Comment: Doing it this way doesn't do anything but duplicate work. With primitive values use either one or the other... why store them permanently in the app scope when you can just set them in the variables scope if that is what you want?

Comment: @MarkAKruger, I think you mean that setting <cfset APPLICATION.datasource = 'MyDSN'> is pointless, correct? I think the original poster is looking for a short term solution as well as a migration plan. Since the DSN is usually set in the APPLICATION scope, it might be a good idea to migrate it there. The same is true with migrating the code to using the default datasource. Either way, some combination of ideas will get the job done.

Comment: Ah... very true. A sort of intermediate step. Ok I buy it :)

Comment: Thanks guys.  Both solutions worked, and yes @EvikJames I am looking for both a short term solution, and a plan moving forward.  Can I give both of you a check mark for an answer? :)

Comment: Give it to Evik - I"m only here to serve :)

Answer (score 4):

You aren't really trying to use "application" variables (which *always* need to be scoped). I suspect your old application.cfm page had something like.

```
<cfapplicatin name="blah"...>

<cfset dsn = 'mydsn'/>
```

And then you were able to do:

```
<cfquery datasource="#dsn#">
```

This approach does *not utilze* the application *scope* ... it is merely taking advantage of the fact that your application.cfm always runs no matter what. What it is actually doing is putting variables in the *variables* scope. Because CF always checks the "variables" scope first you soemthing like #dsn# works - but that is not the same as the application scope.

To mimic this behavior in Application.cfc (as has been suggested) you will need to put your variable in the "onRequest()" function instead of the "onApplicationstart()" function - like so:

```
<cffunction name="onRequest">
<cfset dsn = 'mydsn'/>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: the onrequest function above does not include arguments ... but normally it would... I'm just demonstrating...

Comment: Mark's answer here is the correct one to avoid having to change your legacy code. Ideally Sam's answer represents the best practices, but things are not always ideal.

Answer (score 3):

That is expected. To reference application variables you need to prefix them with application.

Comment: So, every time I want to use `<cfquery datasource="#dsn#">`, I have to change all of the code to `<cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#">`?  That doesn't seem right.  I would have to every page that uses a `cfquery` tag.  The reason I didn't have to do it before when using application.cfm, was that application.cfm was run on every page request?

Comment: If you are using CF9, you can set a default datasource, like this:   <cfset THIS.datasource = 'defaultDS'> You would not longer need to use this:  datasource="#dsn#"

Comment: @EvikJames, I just found out our test server is running CF9, but the upgrade to production hasn't happened yet.  But I have seen that in CF9, the data source is no longer required in a cfquery tag.

Comment: @EvikJames Taking out the `datasource` from the `cfquery` tags worked, but that still doesn't solve my problem of having to change every page the uses the old way of doing `cfquery` tags that include the datasource argument.

Comment: So, you are trying to use #DSN# in all of your existing queries and NOT have to scope it, right?

Comment: this a query on my index.cfm page. `<CFQUERY name="qrySysAdmin" datasource="#dsn#">` This query doesn't work, and it isn't feasible to change every page that is using a query tag now.  So to answer your question, yes.

Comment: @RobM, check out my answer below.  This will probably address your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is in the application scope, you will always need to identify it that way in your .cfm pages.  If you use a variable name without the scope prefix, the application scope is not looked at.

if you want to declare variables in the application.cfc that can be accessed without the application scope in your other pages, simply declare the variables outside of any functions.

```
<component>
   <cfset this.name = "applicationName">
   <cfset otherVar = 'something'>
   <cfset otherVar2 = 'something else'>

   <cffunction name="onApplicationStart>.....</cffunction>
</component>
```

otherVar and otherVar2 can be called without scope prefix on all .cfm pages.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you were not originally using application scoped variables. If the variables were not originally scope with "application." then they were simply in "variables scope" (confusing wording I know) which is accessible by the cfm page hit and others included. That is one big change when moving between application.cfm and application.cfc. The general idea there follows the principle that included CFM files share variables scope and CFC files do not.

If the only change you have to make is changing #dsn# to #appplication.dsn# then just do it and get it over with. There are tools such as WinGrep or even Notepad++ which have find and replace across multiple files.

Comment: Well it appears Application.cfc and/or OnRequestStart don't follow those conventions. +1 to Evik for that info.